# FreeTDS/unixODBC UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'

Tags: bash, sql-server-2005, freetds, unixodbc

I have a stored procedure that has an update to a table with a computed persisted column.
When running the stored procedure from Management Studio it works fine. But when I run it with unixODBC isql I get this error

```
[37000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]UPDATE failed because the following
SET options have incorrect settings: 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS,
ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views
and/or indexes on computed columns and/or query notifications and/or xml data
type methods.
```

I also get this error message from within Management Studio if I put the following in my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

I tried setting these to "ON" in the stored procedure but that did not work.

I also tried adding

```
AnsiNPW = 1
```

in my unixODBC data-source template.

I even tried recreating the stored procedure with those ANSI_PADDING and ANSI_WARNINGS set to ON before the CREATE PROCEDURE clause.

Nothing though seems to make a difference.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into this further, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx) says about SET statements in stored procedures

```
Stored procedures execute with the SET settings specified at execute time except
for SET ANSI_NULLS and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER. Stored procedures specifying SET
ANSI_NULLS or SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER use the setting specified at stored procedure
creation time. If used inside a stored procedure, any SET setting is ignored.
```

So this explains why setting them in the stored procedure did nothing.

To get around this I set them before calling my stored procedure like so:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS ON; EXEC myProc ...
```